# python Get HTML from JS using selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I'm trying to get the div HTML from https://www.workday.com/en-us/company/careers/open-positions.html#?q=.

But the div listing job posts is loaded from `granite.min.js` based on network XHR.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint


path_to_chromedriver = "/Users/RichWin/Documents/chromedriver.exe"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path_to_chromedriver)

driver = browser.get('https://www.workday.com/en-us/company/careers/open-positions.html#?q=')

elem = driver.find_element_by_id('template-content')

soup = BeautifulSoup(elem.get_text, "html.parser")

for tag in soup.find_all('div'):
    pprint(tag)
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please update the question as per: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what's wrong with my question?

Comment: no one is going to do the work for you -> effort evidence is necessary, i.e. show us the code you are having trouble with

Comment: done edited. I'm sorry I'm new here.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so your code has a couple of problems.

a) you need to wait for the `template-content` div to load its content. In the code bellow I use [`implicitly_wait`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) to wait 30 seconds.

b) `find_element_by_id` doesn't return `HTML` but a `Selenium` object. Therefore you cannot pass it to `BeautifulSoup` for parsing.

```
from pprint import pprint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver


url = 'https://www.workday.com/en-us/company/careers/open-positions.html#?q='
path_to_chromedriver = "/Users/RichWin/Documents/chromedriver.exe"

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path_to_chromedriver)
browser.implicitly_wait(30)
browser.get(url)

elem = browser.find_element_by_id('template-content')
elem_html = elem.get_attribute('innerHTML')

soup = BeautifulSoup(elem_html, "html.parser")
for tag in soup.find_all('div'):
    pprint(tag)

browser.quit()
```

Comment: oh. that's why it said:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_class_name'

thank you so much!

Comment: no problem, feel free to accept the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers